# vue, i18n translation: $t in alert()

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, vue-i18n

I'm using Vue 2.6.14 and vue-i18n 8.25
I can't figure it out how to put i18n translation in alert()...

```
 async ChangePassword() {               
       await axios.post('/api/reset-password', 
       this.form).then((response) => {                            
                 alert( {{ $t('Password changed') }} );  
                        })}
```

This doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown where you do this.

Comment: what about `alert( this.$t('Password changed') );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out with `this`

```
 alert( this.$t('Password changed') );
```